# Derive operations from an arbitrary number

Tags: random-number-generator, key-derivation, white-box

I don't really know how to phrase this question, so I'll just mention the idea. This is partially reminiscent (at least in spirit to white box crypto): **Can one derive arithmetic operations from a number?** Is there a formula to do that?

So, the simplest example would be:

```
a = 4
ops = get_operations(a)
print(ops)

/* output:
*
* b = 2
* c = 2
* return b + c
*/
```

The idea is to simply have a way to "derive" a mathematical operation from a value. There are obviously more than "one" operation that could be derived from the above example. The system does not have to be complete.

The flow of such a "derivation" algorithm in my head is as such:

1. Get input (k)
2. Randomly choose an arithmetic operand (P) where `y = k (P) x` and store the operand (P)
3. Pick a random number (x) and store its value
4. Solve for (y) and store its value
5. Now, we have a combination of (P), (x), and (y) that, when solved, would yield the correct input (k).

My question is this: **did someone research this and make a way better algorithm that what I could muster up here**?

Comment: "a way better algorithm" - define "better", that is, by what criteria are you comparing the various possible algorithms?

Comment: "way better" means if there is a name for this topic and has it been researched before by professional mathematicians

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Is there a formula to do that?**

Your example looks like a problem about [Partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) to me. A partition is a way of representing a positive number as a sum of $n$ positive integers, for example:

The partitions of the number $5$ are:

- $5 \space (+0)$
- $4 + 1$
- $3 + 2$
- $3 + 1 + 1$
- $2 + 2 + 1$
- $2 + 1 + 1 + 1$
- $1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1$

Since partitions consider *every possibility* valid, the number for possible ways of any integer $n$ can grow very fast, i.e. the number of possible partitions of the number $100$ is $190,569,292$.

**[There exist some formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory))** (some more complicated or faster than others and some are only approximations).

In your example you only have an operator once, so here $4 + 1$ and $3 + 2$ would be a possiblity.

---

Since you mentioned *"more than one operation"*, a possibility would also be to represent numbers as their [prime factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization), for example:

The prime factorization of the number 22 is:

- $2 \times 11$

There's always only one possiblity to represent a number as it's prime factors (if you don't care about the way you write it ($2 \times 11$ is the same as $11 \times 2$)).

**[There are a lot of factoring algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Factoring_algorithms)**, since this is still a unsolved problem ([Does P = NP ?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem)) and this problem is important for cryptography.

---

I assume that a problem occurs if you'd try to do this with the operators of division and subtraction, for example:

There are infinite possibilities to represent a number as a subtraction, for example:

For the number $5$:

- $6 - 1$
- $7 - 2$
- $8 - 3$
- $9 - 4$
- $\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

I could think of two things: Tweakable Block Cipher, and Tweakable Compression Function.

1. Tweakable Block Cipher:

More info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption_theory).

A Tweakable Block Cipher is defined with the prototype: $f : D \times K \times T \rightarrow D $ where $D$ is the block of data to be encrypted/decrypted with the key $K$ using the block cipher function $f$, that can be efficiently parameterized with $T$.

2. Tweakable Compression Function:

I assume you mean binary operations when you say operation (binary in the sense that there are 2 operands).

Basically, we just build a compression function from a tweakable block cipher using Davies–Meyer construct or any other method to turn a block cipher into a compression function.

$g : D \times D \times T \rightarrow D$

```
f <- blockcipher(d, key, tweak);
g <- compressionfunc(a, b, tweak){ return blockcipher(a, b, tweak) xor a; }
```